# How to call UWP function from ASP.NET Core 2.1 in Windows 10 IoT Core for Raspberry PI 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, uwp, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

I need to call a UWP function that can talk with USB Serial Port from a WebAPI in ASP.NET Core 2.1 but at compile time Visual Studio 2017 get the following error.

Error   NU1201  Project SerialPort is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Project SerialPort supports: uap10.0.17134 (UAP,Version=v10.0.17134)

WebAPI project and UWP project are working well on Raspberry PI3 with Windows 10 IoT as a separate projects. My need is to use UWP and ASP together but seams that is not possible. Asp.NET Core 2.1 seams doesn't support UWP classes for serial port communication and UWP seams not supporting ASP.NET WebAPI integration. How the two worlds can cooperate?

Tanks

Comment: Maybe transferring data between two kind of apps is helpful. Reference [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f1aa9306-e703-441b-a2ae-fdfaa33e04a9/aspnet-5-communication-with-uwp-how-to-enable-loopback?forum=WindowsIoT).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, it is not possible to add the reference for the UWP project from .Net core project at present. It may support when the .Net core 3, you can refer [.NET Core 3 and Support for Windows Desktop Applications](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/05/07/net-core-3-and-support-for-windows-desktop-applications/) about mote detail.

Based on the description, it seems that you want public the hardware info via the web API. If I understood correctly, you may consider developing a web server by yourself and implement the business logic. You can refer the thread below about how to implement a web server in the background app:

[Building a Windows 10 IoT Core background webserver](https://sandervandevelde.wordpress.com/2016/04/08/building-a-windows-10-iot-core-background-webserver/)

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar problem. I think the easiest way might be to reverse the logic. UWP reaches out to WebAPI, rather than WebAPI reaching out to UWP. The WebAPI stores the data, the UWP app gets the data via an http client, and in my case to manage state, the UWP app will store the most recent copy of a JSON file from the API to preserve state in case of power failure. If the power comes back on, it will read the most recent file stored locally prior to reaching out to the API for new data.